# How to keep a link active after refreshing page using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, css

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
   <li 
    ng-class="{ active:   isActive('/dashboards/{{dashboard.id}}/dashboard')}" 
   style="border-right: #ECECEC 1px solid; display: block;" 
   dir-paginate="dashboard in dashboards | itemsPerPage:itemsize"
   data-match-route="/dashboards/{{dashboard.id}}"> 
   <a ng-href="#/dashboards/{{dashboard.id}}/dashboard">
      {{ dashboard.name  }} </a>
   </li>
   </ul>
```

I created a nav bar with number of links, what i wanted is the current link to stay active even after reloading the page, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one variable make it false by default.  Whenever u click on other links make it true. in ng-class put one condition if it false add active class